# Matching multiple column and add to dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, match, multiple-columns

supposed data set,

**df1**

```
num1 num2
27    1
973   3
1410  3
724   1
346   5
```

**df2**

```
 a1     a2   c1      c2
27.0    1   red    apple
131.0   1   blue   banana
2124.0  3   green  apple
1345.0  1   red    orange
346.0   5   blue   grape
```

I want to compare num1 - a1 & num2 - a2, If both conditions are the same,
I want to add the values in c1 and c2 to the list.(assume the beginning is an empty list)

***condition***

1. As you see, num1-a1, num2&a2 `s shape is different.
2. Only the values added to the list are 'c1' and 'c2'

   (num1, num2, a1, a2 are just using to compare & match)
3. The order is jumbled, and the dataframes are different sizes. (different column length)

**The Output what I want**

above example, 2 matches, (27-1 , 346-5), so

```
mylist = [red, apple, blue, grape]
```

How can I do this?

Thank you for reading.

Comment: It seems `'blue', 'banana'` is also matched.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`Series.str.zfill`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.zfill.html) with [`DataFrame.assign`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html) for add `0` for matched with `df2`, then [`DataFrame.merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) with defualt join, last use [`DataFrame.stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) for `Series` and convert to list:

```
mylist = (df1.assign(num1 = df1['num1'].astype(str).str.zfill(4),
                     num2 = df1['num2'].astype(str).str.zfill(3))
              .merge(df2, left_on=['num1','num2'], right_on=['a1','a2'])[['c1','c2']]
              .stack()
              .tolist())
print (mylist)
['green', 'apple', 'orange', 'melon',
 'blue', 'banana', 'purple', 'peach']
```

Comment: Thank you for your efficient code , but now I am reading real data, I modified my question to be a little different from the shape I thought. Can you check again if it`s okay?

Comment: @ybin - I see your answer and it is correct, only omit `.assign(num1 = df1['num1'].astype(str).str.zfill(4),
                     num2 = df1['num2'].astype(str).str.zfill(3))`